# How to append "\" to a pattern or any given string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want the given string `try@to#resolve#` to be converted to `try\@to\#resolve\#`. I have tried the below code and it resulted in error.

How to append the special characters preceding with a `\` in the resulting string, if found in a given string?

```
import re

My_given_string = "try@to#resolve#"
# Here I'm verifying of the string contains special characters or not
if not (My_given_string.isalnum()):
    my_new_string=x = re.sub("\s", "\\s", My_given_string)

print(my_new_string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead for non word chars and sub in the backslash

```py
import re

My_given_string = "try@to#resolve#"
my_new_string = My_given_string
# Here I'm verifying of the string contains special characters or not
if not (My_given_string.isalnum()):
    my_new_string = x = re.sub(r"(?=\W)", r"\\", My_given_string)
print(My_given_string)
print(my_new_string)
```

**Output**

```
try@to#resolve#
try\@to\#resolve\#
```

Comment: It's really helped. Thank you.

Comment: Using print(), it gives the exact output, still if i'm directly using it on console this gives the result as : try\\@to\\#resolve\\#. Can it be resolved ? @Chris

Comment: there is no issue here thats just how the console displays it to you to let you know there is a literal backslash here. Try putting just `"hello\world"` in the console. you will see if gives `'hello\\world'`

Comment: This doesnt mean that there are now 2 backslashes in the string, its just how the console shows you the output of a string with a literal backslasy

Comment: Yes, Correct. Thank You Chris!